# the text is cut in the rmarkdown pdf file

Tags: r, rmarkdown

As you can see in the picture, the text is cut off at the end of the page. What could done to prevent this? I have executed the following code and attached a pic for a better explanation.

I would like to know what to add to the header.tex and in which order.

```
---
title: "simulation"
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
    keep_tex: yes
---
```

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(knitr)
library(report)
```

```
model_1 <- glm(vs ~ mpg * drat, data = mtcars, family = "binomial")
report(model_1)
```

the code in the header.tex for the Yaml header

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{eurosym} 
\usepackage{booktabs,xcolor}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{Confidential - \url{www.Google.com}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}
\addtolength{
\headheight}{1.0cm}
\lhead{Google- Google - \today}
\rhead{\includegraphics[width=4cm]{logo.png}}
```

The warning I get to eventually how to fix the problem but, haven't been able to solve it

```
Warning: (fancyhdr)                \setlength{\headheight}{46.08408pt}.
Warning: (fancyhdr)                You might also make \topmargin smaller to compensate:
Warning: (fancyhdr)                \addtolength{\topmargin}{-5.63133pt}.
```

[image: pic]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on StackOverflow since the solution comes from R, not LaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE. This is not a `LaTeX` question though. This is managed by how you setup `R`. Install `formatR` and then follow Yuhai's instructions here: [Format R code automatically](https://yihui.org/formatr/#2-reformat-r-code) to set an output width for your `glm` call. Also see this answer on `SO`: [How to wrap code and the output in markdown (.Rmd)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33481271/how-to-wrap-code-and-the-output-in-markdown-rmd). I am voting to close the question.